# Pass data for GET request using Hyper

Tags: rust, hyper

I am working on a Twitter API for Rust and am running into issues with passing arguments to my GET request. The code I'm using for the request is given below. `data_body` is something like "screen_name=a_user" and the authorization header is the OAuth authorization required by Twitter (this isn't the issue as it's working with all my other requests).

```
let mut res = client.get("http://httpbin.org/get")
    .body(&data_body[..])
    .header(Authorization(authorization_header))
    .header(ContentType::form_url_encoded())
    .send().unwrap();
```

I started sending this to httpbin.org so I could see the raw request. What I'm getting back is shown below.

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"\", oauth_nonce=\"RH9vZYMCbAtfQAuVh44fhlyGQfQqBCPq\", oauth_signature=\"dTbOyaURct0auVlC%2B8Y7vDFpus0%3D\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1452648640\", oauth_token=\"\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org"
  }, 
  "origin": "0.0.0.0", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

The curl request given by the Twitter api docs have a data portion for the GET request below (I've replaced my keys with empty strings). I can confirm this works for the GET.

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json' --data 'screen_name=twitterdev' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="", oauth_nonce="6a37886cb38b2f5e12dee8fd47aa097c", oauth_signature="zhXDA5JbKRmw2xbJcEqK9sxuu5E%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1452647580", oauth_token="", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

I've tried a bunch of different `ContentType`s from the Hyper API but can't get the args section of the HTTP request populated. I think that's the issue, but I don't have a lot of experience with HTTP so I could very well be wrong. Ultimately the request is returning a 403 (Unauthorized) which is triggered by the missing args. I know my OAuth header is being generated correctly because it's working on all the POST requests and when I copy over the nonce and timestamp from the curl command I get from the Twitter API the signature matches.

Comment: Of note here is that GET requests _really shouldn't_ have bodies. They're not _technically_ forbidden by the spec, but they're not supposed to be meaningful. [Relevant discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Answer (score 4):

As @hamersaw said, "GET parameters" are part of URL, in the query string. If you need to set parameters programatically (if they’re not always the same), the [`Url::set_query_from_pairs`](https://servo.github.io/rust-url/url/struct.Url.html#method.set_query_from_pairs) method can take care of the escaping/encoding for you:

```
use hyper::Url;
let mut url = Url::parse("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json").unwrap();
url.set_query_from_pairs([
    ("screen_name", "twitterdev"),
].iter().cloned());
let res = client.get(url) // ...
```

Comment: As of hyper 0.9, it's `url.query_pairs_mut().append_pair(key, value)`

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. Turns out in a GET request you have to append the body to the request and it will automatically fill out in the packet. Below is the code to get it working.

```
let mut res = client.get("http://httpbin.org/get?screen_name=twitter")
    .header(Authorization(authorization_header))
    .send().unwrap();
```

Comment: That's not the body of the request, they're query parameters (part of the URL).